# Custom UICollectionView Cells are moving around when reloading?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I am just learning UIKit and am wondering how to pass data into a Custom UICollectionViewCell. The way I have it setup right now is that inside my cell I have a function that takes in data and then with that I setup the UI with that data.

```
public func setPost(post: Post) {}
```

And then in the collectionView I can do

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "post", for: indexPath) as! PostView
    cell.vc = self        
    cell.setPost(post: fb.posts[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Which fb.posts is just an array of Post. The problem with doing it this way is that I am getting many weird glitches when scrolling down and back up or leaving the view and coming back. I think this is because of the way I am passing in data that it is re running the code of setPost() causing cells to be rearranged into weird orders and other problems.

If you want more info please let me know or you can check out the github and test it out for yourself.

https://github.com/Joonaynay/StarFeed

Comment: Your UICollectionView implementation is quite strange. You have a class, subclassing UICollectionView and then that same class is the data source and delegate of itself. In general, you would use the UICollectionView as provided by UIKit, and then have your UIViewController subclass (for example, can be any other class) as a data source and delegate of the collection. I don't know if that is actually causing your issues or not, but I would start by dropping that `Grid` class. The way you are populating your cells with data is correct.

Comment: I ended up just switching from a uicollectionview to a scrollview because I couldn't figure it out. The "Grid" you are seeing is just for one view I was using and it seems to work well enough. But in the other situation I had a class CustomCollectionView that just set basic stuff like scroll direction and the UICollectionviewFlowLayout so that in my views I wouldn't have to re add all of those things each time I created a UICollectionView. I could be wrong but I don't think that was the problem. My fault for not being super detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to add in a prepare for reuse override func. Seems to fix all of my problems.
Heres what mine ended up looking like.

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        //Remove all button actions
        infoButton.removeAction(infoButtonAction, for: .touchUpInside)
        likeButton.removeAction(likeButtonAction, for: .touchUpInside)
        imageViewButton.removeAction(imageViewButtonAction, for: .touchUpInside)
        profile.removeAction(profileAction, for: .touchUpInside)
        commentsButton.removeAction(commentsButtonAction, for: .touchUpInside)
        followButton.removeAction(followButtonAction, for: .touchUpInside)
        
        //Remove any other text or images
        imageViewButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        profile.profileImage.image = nil
        titleLabel.text = nil
        date.text = nil
        self.followButton.label.text = nil
    }
```